# MongoDB nested object aggregation sum and sort

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have highly nested mongodb set of objects and i want to sort subofdocuments according to the result of sum their votes for example :

```
{
   "_id":17846384es,
   "company_name":"company1",
   "products":[
       {
         "product_id":"123785",
         "product_name":"product1",
         "user_votes":[
              {
                 "user_id":1,
                  "vote":1
              },
              {
                 "user_id":2,
                  "vote":2
              }
          ]
       },
       {
         "product_id":"98765",
         "product_name":"product2",
         "user_votes":[
              {
                 "user_id":5,
                  "vote":3
              },
              {
                 "user_id":3,
                  "vote":3
              }
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

i want to sort as descending products according to the result of sum their votes
the expected output is

```
{
   "_id":17846384es,
   "company_name":"company1",
   "products":[
       {
         "product_id":"98765",
         "product_name":"product2",
         "user_votes":[
              {
                 "user_id":5,
                  "vote":3
              },
              {
                 "user_id":3,
                  "vote":3
              }
          ]
        "votes":8
       },
       {
         "product_id":"123785",
         "product_name":"product1",
         "user_votes":[
              {
                 "user_id":1,
                  "vote":1
              },
              {
                 "user_id":2,
                  "vote":2
              }
          ],
          "votes":3
       }
    ]
}
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pipeline

```
db.products.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$products" },
    {
        $project: {
            company_name: 1,
            products: 1,
            totalVotes: {
                $sum: "$products.user_votes.vote"
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { totalVotes: -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            company_name: { $first: "$company_name" },
            products: { $push: "$products" }
        }
    }
])
```

would output

```
{
    "_id" : "17846384es",
    "company_name" : "company1",
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "product_id" : "98765",
            "product_name" : "product2",
            "user_votes" : [ 
                {
                    "user_id" : 5,
                    "vote" : 3
                }, 
                {
                    "user_id" : 3,
                    "vote" : 3
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "product_id" : "123785",
            "product_name" : "product1",
            "user_votes" : [ 
                {
                    "user_id" : 1,
                    "vote" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "user_id" : 2,
                    "vote" : 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

In case you want to keep the sum of the votes at the product level as shown in your expected output simply modify the `$project` stage as follows

```
...
{
    $project: {
        company_name: 1,
        products: {
            product_id: 1,
            product_name: 1,
            user_votes: 1,
            votes: { $sum: "$products.user_votes.vote" }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: can i get this result with company information in one result??

Comment: Please show your expected output to avoid any misunderstandings

Comment: Just a note that $sum within the $project stage is only available in MongoDB 3.2 and up.